# Azure PowerShell Error - Output of Get-AzureRmLocation changes when stored to variable

Tags: powershell, azure, location

In Azure PowerShell, version 1.5, when I write the line below:

```
Get-AzureRmLocation | Where {$_.DisplayName -eq "East US 2"}
```

I get the following (expected) output to the console:

- Location: eastus2
- DisplayName: East US 2
- Providers: {Microsoft.Automation, Microsoft.Backup...}

However, when I instead write the following code, *which should (in my understanding) have the exact same output as the above:

```
$location = Get-AzureRmLocation | Where {$_.DisplayName -eq "East US 2"}
$location
```

I now see a different output to the console:

- Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.PSResourceProviderLocation

Further, if I want to call any of the properties that I would expect from any object returned by Get-AzureRmLocation (such as the DisplayName property), I get an error.

Picture attached to prove I'm not losing my mind:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwphR.png)

What is going on?

Comment: Could just be the scope of your $location variable since it is null outside the curly braces but it is difficult to say without the whole script.

Comment: Update: A restart of the server where PowerShell was running fixed the issue entirely. Weird error. Lesson learned: spend 0 time troubleshooting before a complete restart at least once.